# Problem with javacard WebApplication

Tags: java, netbeans, build, javacard

I'm trying to build a javacard webapplication with netbeans, but I'm getting a build error and don't know how to fix it:

```
    [Error] Unable to parse the class file webapplication2/WebApplication2.class. Exception while looking for class webapplication2.WebApplication2: java.io.IOException: Couldnt find: webapplication2/WebApplication2.class. Packager/create FAILED [1 error(s) and 0 warning(s)]
```

Whats wrong here?
I just used the standard template for a javacard web application of Netbeans.

thanks

Comment: Seems that the javacard libraries aren't working on Mac OS X. But are running without problems on Windows XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javacard libraries aren't working on Mac OS X. But are running without problems on Windows XP